# Why use (!fn || zid(handler.fn) === zid(fn)) to (!fn || handler.fn === fn) in zepto.js - event.js?

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events, zepto

In `event.js`, to judge the same handler,  here is code:

```
return handler
  && (!event.e  || handler.e == event.e)
  && (!event.ns || matcher.test(handler.ns))
  && (!fn       || zid(handler.fn) === zid(fn))
  && (!selector || handler.sel == selector)
```

Why use `(!fn || zid(handler.fn) === zid(fn))` to `(!fn || handler.fn === fn)`

Here is the source code of `zid`

```
var _zid = 1
function zid(element) {
  return element._zid || (element._zid = _zid++)
}
```

if I have to judge two functions, `a === b` is enough

why to use `zid(a) === zid(b)`? Maybe some trap?

I don't know why?

Here is the source code of zepto.js event.js: https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/event.js

Comment: Search the code for `_zid` - you'll find there's another spot where a proxy function's `_zid` property is set directly to the same `_zid` as the original function, so two functions that are not `===` can have the same `_zid`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I could find this. Maybe you said in `$.proxy`, but it not matter.